# http curl client doesn't recieve responce from server

Tags: php, curl

I am new in PHP language , I would like to develop a program with PHP for both side (server , client) in order to send HTTP request with data.

in client side I use cul to send HTTP request :

```
<?php
$response = get_web_page("http://192.168.1.110:10000");
$resArr = array();
$resArr = json_decode($response);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($resArr); echo "</pre>";

function get_web_page($url) {
    $options = array (CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false, // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", // handle compressed
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "test", // who am i
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true, // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120, // timeout on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120, // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10 ); // stop after 10 redirects

    $ch = curl_init ( $url );
    curl_setopt_array ( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec ( $ch );
    $err = curl_errno ( $ch );
    $errmsg = curl_error ( $ch );
    $header = curl_getinfo ( $ch );
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo ( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );

    curl_close ( $ch );

    $header ['errno'] = $err;
    $header ['errmsg'] = $errmsg;
    $header ['content'] = $content;
    return $header ['content'];
}
?>
```

the server :

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Permitir al script esperar para conexiones. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Activar el volcado de salida implícito, así veremos lo que estamo obteniendo
* mientras llega. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = '192.168.1.110';
$port = 10000;

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() fail: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() fail: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() fail: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

//clients array
$clients = array();

do {
    $read = array();
    $read[] = $sock;
    $write = NULL;
    $except = NULL;

    $read = array_merge($read,$clients);

    // Set up a blocking call to socket_select
    if(socket_select($read,$write, $except, $tv_sec = 5) < 1)
    {
        continue;
    }

    // Handle new Connections
    if (in_array($sock, $read)) {       

        if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
            echo "socket_accept() fail: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
            break;
        }
        $clients[] = $msgsock;
        $key = array_keys($clients, $msgsock);
        /* Enviar instrucciones. */
        $msg = "\n HELLO C number : {$key[0]}\n";
        socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));

    }

} while (true);

socket_close($sock);
?>
```

the problem with this code is no response from server is received.

any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you have a webserver daemon running on port 10000 which is PHP enabled?

Comment: I think his intention was to have his server code listen to that port itself for requests, though a web server on that port would be much easier.

Comment: the server listen to port 10000 and its @adrress 192.168.1.1.110

Comment: the server display the HTTP header

Comment: curl can handle raw sockets ?